# How to access a certain mapped element in React?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, callback, attributes, react-hooks

I have a map function which returns elements from a JSON callback in a functional component.

I need to find a certain element from the mapped callback by its attribute and color it.

Without React.js, I'd probably use the document, but I understand it is best to use a variable reference. The thing is my element is reachable from a string and has no permanent order. What should I do?

Example for my code:

```
   let x = [{name: 'elephant', symbol: 'e'}, {name: 'rabbit', symbol: 'r'}];

   let mapped = x.map(x =>
        <button
            title={x.name} // <- I want only: [title="elephant"]
        >
            {x.symbol}
        </button>
    )

    React.useEffect(() => {
          
    }, [])
```

This is how I'd use the document (no React.js):

```
document.querySelector('button[title="elephant"]').style.color = 'green';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this, one is to filter (can have multiple matches) beforehand:

```
let mapped = x
  .find((x) => x.name === "elephant")
  .map((x) => <button title={x.name} style={{color: 'green'}}>{x.symbol}</button>);
```

You can also find (for a single specific item) and then use the value:

```
let specific = x.find((x) => x.name === "elephant");

// Then use it
<button title={specific.name} style={{color: 'green'}}>{specific.symbol}</button>;
```

Answer (score 0):

It should fit your need:

```
<button
  title={x.name} // <- I want only: [title="elephant"]
  style={x.name === 'elephant' ? { color: 'green'} : {}}
>
  {x.symbol}
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you want to account for the possibility to add styles to objects other than `elephant` in the array, consider this pattern.

```js
let x = [
  {name: 'elephant', symbol: 'e', color: 'green'},
  {name: 'rabbit', symbol: 'r', color: 'red'},
  {name: 'dog', symbol: 'd'},
];

let mapped = x.map(x =>
  <button
    title={x.name}
    style={x.color ? {color: x.color} : undefined}
  >
    {x.symbol}
  </button>
)
```